# Birthday .csv List - Notification if Birthday is in 1-5 Days of today

Tags: powershell

I have a `.csv` list like this:

```
EntryDate,Name,Birthday of Member
04.12.2012,User Name, 28.12.1984
.
.
.
```

I want to compare each birthday in this `.csv` file with the actual date and send a notification email if the birthday is in the next 4 days.

*edit:*

```
$CSVList = get-content D:\Geburtstage.csv
$List  = ConvertFrom-Csv -InputObject $CSVList -Delimiter ";"
$new = $list | select Stand,"Name, Vorname",@{name="Geburtsdatum";expression= {$([datetime]::ParseExact($_.Geburtsdatum, "dd/MM/yyyy", $null  ))}}
```

Comment: now, im having a Date object. But how can in compare the Day+Month with the actual day?

Comment: Assuming you want to run this every day, or every week day, do you really want to send 4 notifications about the same person?

Comment: joel, you're right. Every birthday is now reported only 1x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the following file :

```
EntryDate,Name,Birthday of Member
04.12.2012,User Name1, 28.12.1984
04.12.2012,User Name2, 12.12.1984
04.12.2012,User Name3, 28.12.1984
```

You can test the following to find today birthday:

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\birth.csv | where {$_."Birthday of Member" -like "$((get-date).Day).$((get-date).Month)*"} | % {$_.name}
```

You can test the following to find birthday from 1 to 5 days:

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\birth.csv | where {$a=$_."Birthday of Member" -match "(\d+)\.(\d+).*"; (Get-Date) -gt (Get-Date -Day $matches[1] -Month $matches[2] -Year (get-date).Year).AddDays(-6)} | % {$_.name}
```

I just use a regular expression to retreive the day and the month and compute the date of the birthday minus 6. If today is greater than this date it match the filter.

---

**Edited**

If you've got a ';' as delimiter you just have to add `-Delimiter ';'` to import-csv

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\birth.csv -Delimiter ';' | where {$a=$_."Birthday of Member" -match "(\d+)\.(\d+).*"; (Get-Date) -gt (Get-Date -Day $matches[1] -Month $matches[2] -Year (get-date).Year).AddDays(-6)} | % {$_.name}
```

Your second trouble comes from the fact that you have a separator different from '.' between   day and month of the birthdate (the '.' is part of the regular expression).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the great answer!! Two things: i must use a -delimiter ";". This was a Typo in my Example! Sorry for that! Your first Example works fine if i use the delimiter an use a * instead of the . between (get-date).day) and the (get-date).Month. The Second Example throws me all Users..?

Comment: The exact syntax of the file: entrydate;user, name;Birthday of Member. There is a , between user an name! sorry for that typo